# Glassfish: Unable to map datasource JNDI name to portable name using glassfish-web.xml

Tags: glassfish, eclipselink, java-ee-6

I'm going slightly insane trying to make a Java EE 6 webapp portable between Glassfish AS 3.x and JBoss AS 6 (and 7 when released).

Because each server maps JNDI names for datasources differently, I need to specify an application-private internal name for the datasource in persistence.xml then use glassfish-web.xml or jboss-web.xml (as appropriate) to map that to a real datasource name in the server.

The theory is simple (well, for EE):

- Use internal name in persistence.xml, eg "my-datasource"
- Add a resource-ref entry to web.xml declaring that your app needs a resource called "my-datasource"
- Add a mapping in glassfish-web.xml and jboss-web.xml with the appropriate server's syntax, declaring that "my-datasource" should be mapped to the app server provided data source named "real-DS-created-by-admin"

Unfortunately, the theory is about as far as it goes, because for the life of me I cannot make it work in Glassfish AS 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.2 beta, JBoss AS 6, or JBoss AS 7 beta. Right now I'm focusing on getting it working on Glassfish.

Glassfish reports "Invalid resource : my-datasource__pm" when I try to deploy an app that references "my-datasource" in persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="org.example_glassfish-webxml-datasource-jndi-mapping_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>my-datasource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and maps it to a known existing datasource via web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- servlet declarations etc elided ... --> 

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>my-datasource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

... and glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>my-datasource</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>realdsname</jndi-name>
  </resource-ref>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

"asadmin list-jndi-entries" shows the actual datasource JNDI name exactly as it appears in glassfish-web.xml as well as listing another entry with a "__pm" suffix that's generated by Glassfish:

```
$ asadmin list-jndi-entries
.... unrelated output ....
realdsname__pm: javax.naming.Reference
realdsname: javax.naming.Reference
```

Needless to say, this is driving me completely up the wall. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Further investigation suggests that this may be (yet another) Glassfish bug, since even a simple test case fails. See: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17024

Comment: Nope, apparently it's working as designed. persistence.xml can't use these mapping features like everything else can, it has to use container global names directly.

Comment: Further discussion on the Glassfish forums in an attempt to shed some light on this insanity: http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/indirection-persistencexml-datasource-webxml-and-glassfish-webxml-how

Comment: Pity this hasn't moved forward - it's a real pain. My app was working in both jboss and glassfish before, but now JBoss 7.1.1 is insisting on having a java:/ prefix for the datasource name in the server config. And glassfish doesn't like that.

Comment: It's Java EE, of course it hasn't moved forward. Java EE 6 is only barely usable now, after years of bug fixing, workarounds and cleanups. Oracle are too busy Cloud-ifying EE 7 to bother with a 6.1 that might actually fix things. Me? Bitter? Never.

Comment: @mdma Your best bet AFAIK is using a <data-source/> element in web.xml or a @@DataSourceDefinition annotation, and mapping the DS to the java:app/ namespace. I've long since given up on trying to make my EE code portable, esp as Glassfish is *still* too buggy, and just switched to targeting exclusively JBoss AS 7. At least that way I don't have to restart the AS every redeploy to avoid PermGenSpace OOM crashes from classloader leaks in Glassfish...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, here's the situation.

It's not supposed to work (see http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17024) and apparently that's OK.

Apparently everybody defines their data sources in annotations, in web.xml <data-source/> clauses, or just targets only one app server. All the mapping stuff is completely non-functional for JPA even though it works fine for @Resource injection, JNDI lookups, Spring, etc.

I've added this to my already-way-too-long [java EE 6 warts and traps page](http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2011/07/java-ee-6-traps-pitfalls-and-warts-list.html).

Comment: The fact that you can't use component environment JNDI names for something that spans components like the persistence context actually makes sense to me. Maybe i've been doing EE so long my brain has warped to fit it. The fact that you can't write a JNDI name which both JBoss and GlassFish will accept is enraging rubbish, though. It's just a string! A STRING!!