# How to bundle glassfish-resources.xml with distributed .jar file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, resources, glassfish

The [glassfish docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24929/deploying-applications.htm#giydj) says:

> An application-scoped resource is defined in the
>   glassfish-resources.xml deployment descriptor file. This file is
>   placed in the META-INF directory of the module or application archive.

However, it does not seem to be the case. When I do, and deploy the .jar file to my Glassfish 3.1.2 server, he throws a couple of exceptions, and says:

> Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : jdbc/malivechat-db-ds__pm

The JNDI name of my resource is actually "jdbc/malivechat-db-ds". So I do not understand where the underscore "__pm" comes from (?). However, if I add my resources separately, say I do this through the admin console or let Netbeans deploy the package for me, all works just fine.

**Is there no way to bundle the glassfish-resources.xml file with our distributed .jar file?**

The way I see it, it just have to be. Although adding resources seems to be application server specific (why? I mean why "glassfish-resources.xml" and not just "resources.xml"?), surely there should be a way to add all vendor specific *-resources.xml file to our .jar file and thus "support" a set of different application servers?

Either way, doing it the way glassfish docs says does not seem to work, or I've got something completely wrong.

Comment: This seem similar to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660416/glassfish-unable-to-map-datasource-jndi-name-to-portable-name-using-glassfish-w

Comment: Similar perhaps but not helpful. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: I have the same [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738828/unable-create-jms-resources-in-glassfish-v3-1-2-using-glassfish-resources-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your problem: [Bug 243034 - The file glassfish-resources.xml in project is not executed on Glassfish in order to install a jdbc pool](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243034)

Probably related:

[How to automatically set up JTA data source/resources in Glassfish on deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872948/how-to-automatically-set-up-jta-data-source-resources-in-glassfish-on-deploy/29455676#29455676)

[how to deploy a webapp and create its resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530730/how-to-deploy-a-webapp-and-create-its-resources) (with proposed solution)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by specifying JNDI application namespace in my resource name.
Try to change JNDI resource name in `glassfish-resources.xml` to
something like this:
`jndi-name="java:app/malivechat-db-ds"`

and lookup your resource with same syntax. For example in `persistence.xml`:

`<jta-data-source>java:app/malivechat-db-ds</jta-data-source>`